# Symfony2 choice widget ordering of preferred_choices

Tags: forms, symfony, drop-down-menu, formbuilder, dropdownchoice

I have a registration form with a country select. Most of the users are from the UK, and then a way behind them are from Ireland. The rest of the world together are a very small proportion at the moment. Therefore I would like to put UK and Ireland at the top, as preferred choices:

```
->add('country', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => Locale::getDisplayCountries(\Locale::getDefault()),
    'preferred_choices' => array('GB', 'IE')
))
```

This works ok, BUT "Ireland" appears above "United Kingdom" in the separated, preferred options.

Is there any way to set the order of these so that UK appears top of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created issue:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5136

Hopefully will be looked at in sf 2.2

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities)?

You could guild your form by analogy to:

```
$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not really what Im after. I dont want to change the order of all of the options, just the preferred ones. Also Im not using an entity type so can't even use the query builder!

Answer (score 0):

Until this is fixed, you can use a little JavaScript to at least force a default. Example which uses JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* Set the default country to US */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select option").filter(function() {
      //may want to use $.trim in here
      return $(this).text() == "United States"; 
  }).prop('selected', true);
});
</script>
```